# Superconductors and conservation of angular momentum

Tags: superconductivity

One of the diagrams in my textbook show a superconductor in a magnetic field along with some arrows over it which presumably indicate current.

Also all the current arrows seem to be pointing in one direction indicating that there is a clockwise/counterclockwise current and current means that (free?) electrons are indeed moving. Now if electrons are moving in same direction across the breadth of the Superconductor then shouldn't they also carry with them an angular momentum in the direction of their rotation.

But the superconductor as a whole was neutral so there was no net torque on the superconductor. If so that implies that the Angular momentum must remain conserved. But apparently this is no the case.

Now my question is:

> How does the superconductor counter the electrons' angular momentum.

Comment: Can you provide us with a picture of the diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the electrons do carry some angular momentum.  However, your question is "How does the superconductor *counter* the electrons' angular momentum?"  Answer: the superconductor does *not* counter the electrons' angular momentum.  If the superconducting loop were entirely isolated and started with no current, then somehow created its own current, then the loop would rotate in the direction opposite to the electron flow and the net angular momentum would be zero.  Its rotation speed would be in inverse ratio to the mass of the loop to the electrons' mass: a very small value.  But under real laboratory conditions, the loop would not be isolated.  It would be held still by external apparatus while the current is induced, so the "reverse-direction" component of the angular momentum component would be absorbed by the surrounding apparatus.

Comment: Just as a curiosity would you be able to observe similar rotations in normal circuits it they were kept in a perfectly isolated conditions

Comment: Yes, except that resistance would stop the current *and* the rotation of the loop.  The angular momentum would not change unless the loop (and/or current) interacts with the external universe.